# Facing Problem while returning object in response Example in Swashbuckle.Examples

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.examples

I'm using [Swashbuckle.Examples](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.Examples) in Web API for better documentation. It is working fine for Swashbuckle Sample response but when I'm using Sample Example 
When I run the project it is showing an Error.

My controller

```
 [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<ReasonReponsesuccessMessage_list>))]
 [SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(IEnumerable<ReasonReponseSuccessExample_list>))]
 [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<ReponseEmptyMessage>))]
 [SwaggerOperation("List reasons")]
 [ActionName("Reasons")]
 [Route("api/{Id}")]
 [HttpGet]
 public HttpResponseMessage GetReasons(string Id)
 {
 }
```

Response Example Class

```
  public class ReasonReponseSuccessExample_list : IExamplesProvider
    {
        object IExamplesProvider.GetExamples()
        {
            ReasonReponsesuccessMessage_list ReasonReponsesuccessMessage_list = new ReasonReponsesuccessMessage_list();

            ReasonReponsesuccessMessage_list.Message = "Success";
            ReasonReponsesuccessMessage_list.Data = new List<tbl_reason>
            {
                new tbl_reason{ id="SAA133",primary_name="Wrong Invoice",alt_name="Wrong Invoice"},
                new tbl_reason{ id="B97123",primary_name="Payment Problem",alt_name=""}
            };
            ReasonReponsesuccessMessage_list.Extras = "";
            ReasonReponsesuccessMessage_list.Success = true;
            return ReasonReponsesuccessMessage_list;
        }
    }
```

**ERROR**:

> Expected examplesProviderType to implement
>   Swashbuckle.Examples.IExamplesProvider.
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[IgniteAPI.Payload.ReasonReponseSuccessExample_list]
>   does not.

I'm Getting this error in global.asmx

`GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the error, you need to specify type that implements 
 `IExamplesProvider`

Use

```
[SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(ReasonReponseSuccessExample_list))]
```

instead of

```
[SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(IEnumerable<ReasonReponseSuccessExample_list>))]
```

Comment: Thanks you so much